How can I resolve a Python error when copying file in Linux with space in directory name?
I'm trying to copy a file in Linux but getting an error, likely because of a space in the name.
In a Python 3.7 script, I defined:
import os
today_path = '20240529'
source_dir = f'/some/file/path/{today_path}'
target_dir = f'/some/other/path/2024 data/{today_path}'
os.system(f'cp {source_dir}/my_file {target_dir}/Data')

But it returns:
cp: target 'data/20240529/Data/' is not a directory

I guess this happens because of "2024 data". This isn't my path so I won't ask users to change it unless necessary. Is there a way to handle this?
I can accept a solution using shutil.copy as well. I tried but that didn't work, maybe for the same reason.

You gotta enclose the path in double quotes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/648577/copying-files-from-directories-having-spaces-in-its-name
